# Can you listen on keyboard events on Android

Tags: android, keyboard-events

I'm looking for a way to listen to `keydown` & `keyup` events in native Android, when the user is using a soft keyboard, similar to how these events work in Javascript. I'm looking for just the event and timestamp in order to analyze keyboard dynamics.

Couldn't find documentation for this.

--EDIT--

This for an SDK that will be called from the root view. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for how to detect when key is pressed, try this code:

```
@Override    
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) { //I pressed space button
         //some code when space is pressed
         return true;
        }
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Note that you can override this only in activity and perhaps send some event if you are in fragment